# Regular expression for matching comment and first_line_of_entry

Tags: regex

For the below input(small), with two entries

Comment starts with `#`

Entry is multi-line with backslash(`\`) for continuation

First line of the first entry has comment

First line of second entry does not have comment.

```
# Arista
# aristaBgp4V2EstablishedNotification   aristaBgp4V2PeerState
1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.4.1.0.1    0x3330000 1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.4.1.1.2.1.13(1,2)\
                                        # aristaBgp4V2PeerLocalPort
                                        1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.4.1.1.2.1.6(3,0)\
                                        # aristaBgp4V2PeerRemotePort
                                        1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.4.1.1.2.1.9(4,0)

1.3.6.1.4.1.60029.3.8.1.0.1  0x31210004 1.3.6.1.4.1.60029.3.8.0.0.3.1.3(1,2)\
                                        # aristaLastSwOverReason
                                        1.3.6.1.4.1.60029.3.8.0.0.4(3,0)
```

regex should retrieve  `('aristaBgp4V2EstablishedNotification', '1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.4.1.0.1')` where `'aristaBgp4V2EstablishedNotification'` as part of comment, which is the
 name of dotted notation `'1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.4.1.0.1'` in the first line of first entry(multi-line)

regex should not retrieve dotted notation `1.3.6.1.4.1.60029.3.8.1.0.1` from second entry, because there is no corresponding comment attached to that entry.

---

For below input(bigger):

```
# Arista 
# aristaBgp4V2EstablishedNotification   aristaBgp4V2PeerState
1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.4.1.0.1    0x55510000 1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.4.1.1.2.1.13(1,2)\
                                        # aristaBgp4V2PeerLocalPort
                                        1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.4.1.1.2.1.6(3,0)\
                                        # aristaBgp4V2PeerRemotePort
                                        1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.4.1.1.2.1.9(4,0)
# aristaBgp4V2BackwardTransitionNotificationaristaBgp4V2PeerState


1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.4.1.0.2    0x06710001 1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.4.1.1.2.1.13(1,2)\
                                        # aristaBgp4V2PeerLocalPort
                                        1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.4.1.1.2.1.6(3,0)\
                                        # aristaBgp4V2PeerRemotePort
                                        1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.4.1.1.2.1.9(4,0)\
                                        # aristaBgp4V2PeerLastErrorCodeReceived
                                        1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.4.1.1.3.1.1(5,0)\
                                        # aristaBgp4V2PeerLastErrorSubCodeReceived
                                        1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.4.1.1.3.1.2(6,0)\
                                        # aristaBgp4V2PeerLastErrorReceivedText
                                        1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.4.1.1.3.1.4(7,0)
#portTestResultNotification

1.3.6.1.4.1.4996.1.1.10.1.0.14   0x212a000d  1.3.6.1.4.1.4996.1.1.10.1.1.2(1,0)\
                                            1.3.6.1.4.1.4996.1.1.10.1.1.3(2,0)\
                                            1.3.6.1.4.1.4996.1.1.10.1.2.1(3,0)\
                                            1.3.6.1.4.1.4996.1.1.10.1.1.98(4,0)\
                                            1.3.6.1.4.1.4996.1.1.10.1.1.99(5,0)\
                                            1.3.6.1.4.1.4996.1.1.10.1.5.4.1.5(6,7)\
                                            1.3.6.1.4.1.4996.1.1.10.1.5.4.1.12(8,0)\
                                            1.3.6.1.4.1.4996.1.1.10.1.5.4.1.13(9,0)\
                                            1.3.6.1.4.1.4996.1.1.10.1.5.4.1.14(10,0)

# BigIp    
#diskVolumeUsageNotification

1.3.6.1.4.1.4997.1.1.10.1.0.17   0x212a000e  1.3.6.1.4.1.4997.1.1.10.1.1.2(1,0)\
                                            1.3.6.1.4.1.4997.1.1.10.1.1.3(2,0)\
                                            1.3.6.1.4.1.4997.1.1.10.1.2.1(3,0)\
                                            1.3.6.1.4.1.4997.1.1.10.1.1.98(4,0)\
                                            1.3.6.1.4.1.4997.1.1.10.1.1.100(5,0)\
                                            1.3.6.1.4.1.4997.1.1.10.1.1.101(6,0)\
                                            1.3.6.1.4.1.4997.1.1.10.1.4.4.1.7(7,8)\
                                            1.3.6.1.4.1.4997.1.1.10.1.4.4.1.5(9,0)

1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.3.8.1.0.1  0x22210004 1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.3.8.0.0.3.1.3(1,2)\
                                        # aristaRedundancyLastSwOverReason
                                        1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.3.8.0.0.4(3,0)

# wlsrStaImpersonation                          wlsrNodeMac
1.3.6.1.4.1.13323.2.3.1.1.100.6.1002 0x3337000f 1.3.6.1.4.1.13323.2.3.1.1.100.100.5(1,0)\
                                                # wlsrLocation
                                                1.3.6.1.4.1.13323.2.3.1.1.1.1.1.20(2,3)
```

regex should retrieve:

```
('aristaBgp4V2EstablishedNotification', '1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.4.1.0.1')
('aristaBgp4V2BackwardTransitionNotificationaristaBgp4V2PeerState', '1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.4.1.0.2 ')
('portTestResultNotification', '1.3.6.1.4.1.4996.1.1.10.1.0.14')
('diskVolumeUsageNotification', '1.3.6.1.4.1.4997.1.1.10.1.0.17')
('wlsrStaImpersonation','1.3.6.1.4.1.13323.2.3.1.1.100.6.1002')
```

Just to remind `1.3.6.1.4.1.30064.3.8.1.0.1` is not part of the output because there is no comment corresponding to that entry

---

To retrieve **first string** from the comment, regex is: `#\s*\w+`

To retrieve **OID in first line** of the entry, regex is `(?<!\\\n)^((?:[1-9][0-9]{0,3}|0)(?:\.(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0))+)`

---

How to combine these two regex to retrieve these two tokens?

Comment: What should you match with 2 consecutive comments like: `# Arista ` and `# aristaBgp4V2EstablishedNotification`?

Comment: @Julio Comment nearest to the entry should be matched... Query updated

Comment: diskVolumeUsageNotification has 2 numbers (first one ends with 17 and second one ends with 1) Should we match both or just the first?

Comment: @Julio second one ends with `1`? I don't see that in the query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex to get your matches in 2 capture groups:

```
^#\s*(\S+).*\s+([\d.]+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xFFZO0/3)

**RegEx Detail:**

- `^#\s*`: Match `#` at line start followed by 0 or more whitespaces
- `(\S+)`: Match 1+ non-space characters in first capture group
- `.*`: Match rest of the line
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `([\d.]+)`: Match 1+ digit or dot characters in second capture group

Comment: Would you suggest `#\s*(\S+).*\s+([\d.]+)`?

Comment: Check updated answer, we need start anchor as well. This regex is much more efficient than previous one

Comment: Yes... i do not need complex regex for dotted numbers....Because am not validating those dotted numbers.. All are valid numbers...

Answer (score 1):

*You can use some junk regex, or do it right* -

`(?m)^\#[^\S\r\n]*(\S+).*\s+^(?!\#)[^\S\r\n]*(\S+)`

https://regex101.com/r/C8oHsr/1

The items are in groups 1 and 2

Readable version

```
 (?m)                          # Multi-line mode
 ^                             # BOL
 \# [^\S\r\n]*                 # Comment and optional horizontal whitespace
 ( \S+ )                       # (1), Non-whitespace
 .*                            # The rest of line
 \s+                           # Required Whitespace (line break)
 ^                             # BOL
 (?! \# )                      # Not a comment line
 [^\S\r\n]*                    # Optional horizontal whitespace
 ( \S+ )                       # (2), Non-whitespace
```

Note you can change this `[^\S\r\n]` to `\h` if using PCRE style engines.